# how to see the table of virtual function

Tags: c#

I have two class.One class inherits from another. Also I use polymorphism with virtual function.  Can I see the table of virtual function? I want to understand the mechanism of virtual functions.

```
public class A
{
 public virtual void foo()
 {
 }
}

public class B:A
{
  public override void foo()
  {
  }
}
...
A a=new B();
a.SomeMethod();//show table of virtual function
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to "see" a table of virtual functions to "understand" polymorphism. In this case, understanding without seeing may be a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not possible to actually see the virtual table since the CLR polymorphism mechanism isn't based on a pointer allocated for each instance that points to a virtual table like you probably familiar with from C++ language.

.NET keeps a pointer to a type object for each instance, which respectively points to a method table that manages the actual implementation to be called.

Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti) for more details.

Comment: I have to quibble a bit with this answer.  There's no significant difference between a C++ v-table and the .NET MethodTable.  Structure and usage is identical.  Pretty important to make C# competitive with C++.  Only detail is that it also contains non-virtual methods, taken advantage of in C# by making every method call an indirect call.  Buys a very cheap null-reference check.